# Highchart Pie Chart shows "slice 0.0%" when loading data from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I try to load data from CSV data to create a pie chart. 
There always slice showing "slice:0.0%". However, in my CSV data, there is no such a data called slice. I'm wondering if this is because the highchart's default setting or it's because I used the wrong way to read CSV data file.

[Jsfiddle_code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wreck/8tm2ysbp/1/)

Below is photo of the chart.[image: chart]

```js
var pie_bl = Papa.parse(document.getElementById('pie_bl').innerHTML);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  data: {
    rows: pie_bl.data
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Pie Chart_csv'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mholt/PapaParse/master/papaparse.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<pre id="pie_bl" style="display:none">Category,Allocation
a,0.45,
b,0.5,
c,1.25,
d,0.15, 
e,0.1,
f,0.55,
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV data in `<pre>` tag is ending with a , and a `new-line`. In CSV this will be treated as another entry. This is why it is showing Slice: 0.0.

By default Highcharts assigns the label as Slice and value as 0 if not mentioned. So your `<pre>` tag should look something like this

```
<pre id="pie_bl" style="display:none">
    Category,Allocation
    a,0.45
    a,0.45,
    b,0.5,
    c,1.25,
    d,0.15, 
    e,0.1,
    f,0.55</pre>
```

Update your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8tm2ysbp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your values will be with proper comma

```
<pre id="pie_bl" style="display:none">Category,Allocation,
a,0.45,
b,0.5,
c,1.25,
d,0.15, 
e,0.1,
f,0.55,</pre>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tm2ysbp/3/)